# A three-parameter Pareto distribution in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to define a Pareto distribution using `scipy.stats.pareto`, but the model I am using is in a quite different form which has three parameter, where `f(x) = (gamma(alpha + k) * lambda**alpha * x**(k - 1)) / (gamma(alpha) * gamma(k) * (lambda + x)**(alpha + k))`.

I have also tried to set `k = 1` in order to reduce the distribution to a 2-parameter distribution, where `f(x) = (alpha * lambda**alpha) / (lambda + x)**(alpha + 1)`. However, I am still unable to put the parameter into `scipy.stats.pareto`.

I have created a case where `alpha = 6.54545` and `lambda = 2772.72727` which should give a `mean = 500` and `std = 600`, but what I got was `Mean = 3272.7276793445976` and `std = 600.0005828803438`. I know this is caused by a different version of pdf, but I want to know if it is possible to use the `scipy.stats.pareto` function or any built-in function instead of writing up a new function for this distribution.

Comment: What are alpha and lambda and what is the range of x? Note that the PDF should integrate to one over there range of the distribution.

Comment: Do you mean for the 2-parameter one? All alpha, lambda, k and x > 0, and the pdf is from the formulae from IFoA, so I guess it should integrate to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution you describe is usually called [Beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution), and is implemented as [`betaprime`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.betaprime.html#scipy.stats.betaprime) in SciPy. It's more general than the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution). One might call it a generalized Pareto distribution but I wouldn't because that term also means [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution). Can we standardize on Wikipedia usage of these names, please?

The relevant parameters of `betaprime` are `a`, `b`, and `scale`, which translate from your notation as `a=k`, `b=alpha`, and `scale=lamda`

A demo:

```
from scipy.stats import betaprime
alpha = 6.54545
lamda = 2772.72727
k = 1
print(betaprime.mean(k, alpha, scale=lamda))
print(betaprime.std(k, alpha, scale=lamda))
```

prints

```
500.0004093445978
600.0005828803438
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I do want to follow the wikipedia's name, but the problem is that I have never heard of this name or distribution before, the only source I have seen the distribution is from the formulae table, and it is marked as Pareto distribution (three parameter version). Thank you so much for your help, I have been stuck on this for a few days already.