# Creating sample from custom distribution using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

I am trying to get some sample from a given distribution, in fact, it is a 3-parameter Pareto distribution. Here are the codes:

```
from scipy.stats import gamma, rv_continuous

class pareto3_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x,alpha,lambd,k):
        return (gamma(alpha + k) * lambd**alpha * x**(k - 1)) / (gamma(alpha) * gamma(k) * (lambd + x)**(alpha + k))
pareto3 = pareto3_pdf(name="pareto")


x = pareto3.rvs(alpha = 3,lambd = 4,k = 2)
print(x)
```

and the output: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'rv_frozen' and 'int'`

I am not quite sure how to fix this. If anyone has any suggestion it would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

edit:

I have now changed the code, but it keeps giving negative values.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
from scipy.special import gamma

class pareto3_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x,alpha,lambd,k):
        return (gamma(alpha + k) * lambd**alpha * x**(k - 1)) / (gamma(alpha) * gamma(k) * (lambd + x)**(alpha + k))
pareto3 = pareto3_pdf(name="pareto")
pare3 = pareto3.rvs(alpha = 5,lambd = 4,k = 2)
print(pare3)
```

and if I try to simplify this into a 2-parameter model, `OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')` error popup.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
from scipy.special import gamma

class pareto2_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x,alpha,lambd):
        return (alpha * lambd**alpha / (lambd + x)**(alpha + 1))
pareto2 = pareto2_pdf(name="pareto2")
pare2 = pareto2.rvs(alpha = 2,lambd = 2)
print(pare2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940900) your distribution is available in SciPy as `betaprime(k, alpha, scale=lamda)`, so sampling it is built-in. A little test:

```
from scipy.stats import betaprime
alpha, lamda, k = 5, 4, 2
sample = betaprime.rvs(k, alpha, scale=lamda, size=1000)
print(sample.mean())
print(betaprime.mean(k, alpha, scale=lamda))
```

prints

```
2.0134570579012108
2.0
```

Close enough. (Of course, the mean of a random sample is random.)

Comment: Thanks, and I have found out that the two parameters version is in fact the Lomax distribution, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You have to import gamma from [scipy.special](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html) instead of [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html). 
The reason is that [scipy.stats.gamma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy.stats.gamma) is distribution and [scipy.special.gamma](http://scipy.special.gamma) is the gamma function.

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous 
from scipy.special import gamma 

class pareto3_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x,alpha,lambd,k):
        return (gamma(alpha + k) * lambd**alpha * x**(k - 1)) /(gamma(alpha) * gamma(k) * (lambd + x)**(alpha + k))
pareto3 = pareto3_pdf(name="pareto")
x = pareto3.rvs(alpha = 3,lambd = 4,k = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it keep giving me negative number, any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you have to add _argcheck method to your class. But I don't know how to do it right